# Twitter bootstrap hide element on small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have this code:

```
<footer class="row">
  <nav class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>Text 1</li>
      <li>Text 2</li>
      <li>Text 3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>Text 4</li>
      <li>Text 5</li>
      <li>Text 6</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>Text 7</li>
      <li>Text 8</li>
      <li>Text 9</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>Text 10</li>
      <li>Text 11</li>
      <li>Text 12</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Four blocks with some texts inside. They are equal in width, I've set `col-sm-3` to all of them and what I want to do is to hide the last `nav` on extra small devices. I've tried to use `hidden-xs` on that `nav` and it hides it, but in the same time I want the other blocks to expand (change class from `col-sm-3` to `col-sm-4`) `col-sm-4 X 3 = 12`.

Any solution?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

On small device : `4 columns x 3 (= 12)   ==> col-sm-3`

On extra small : `3 columns x 4 (= 12)    ==> col-xs-4`

```
 <footer class="row">
        <nav class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>Text 1</li>
            <li>Text 2</li>
            <li>Text 3</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>Text 4</li>
            <li>Text 5</li>
            <li>Text 6</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>Text 7</li>
            <li>Text 8</li>
            <li>Text 9</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="hidden-xs col-sm-3">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>Text 10</li>
            <li>Text 11</li>
            <li>Text 12</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>
```

As you say, hidden-xs is not enough, you have to combine xs and sm class.

---

Here is links to the official doc about [available responsive classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) and about the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

*Have in head :*

- **1 row = 12 cols**
- *For **X**tra**S**mall device* : **col-xs**-__
- *For **SM**all device* : **col-sm**-__
- *For **M**e**D**ium Device*: **col-md**-__
- *For **L**ar**G**e Device* : **col-lg**-__
- Make **visible only** (hidden on other) : **visible-md** (just visible in
  medium [not in lg xs or sm])
- Make **hidden only** (visible on other) : **hidden-xs** (just hidden in
  XtraSmall)

Comment: It appears that in Bootstrap 4 you need to specify bubbling via hidden-SIZE-(up|down).  Ex:  `hidden-sm-down`

Comment: For Bootstrap 2, use class `hidden-phone`

Answer (score 90):

**Bootstrap 4**

The [display (hidden/visible) classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) are changed in Bootstrap 4. To hide on the `xs` viewport use:

`d-none d-sm-block`

Also see: [Missing visible-** and hidden-** in Bootstrap v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351353/missing-visible-and-hidden-in-bootstrap-v4/45844579#45844579)

---

**Bootstrap 3** (original answer)

Use the `hidden-xs` utility class..

```
<nav class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>Text 10</li>
        <li>Text 11</li>
        <li>Text 12</li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

http://bootply.com/90722

Comment: I've used that class but it was not helpfull, but in your example you added some other classes to the other nav's that changed their display from 25% to 33% wide. That was it! Thx

Comment: You're welcome, but I did miss that you already mentioned using 'hidden-xs` in your example. +1 for @Jahnux73 answer

Answer (score 23):

### **For Bootstrap 4.0 there is a change**

See the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

In order to hide the content on mobile and display on the bigger devices you have to use the following classes:

```
d-none d-sm-block
```

The first class set display none all across devices and the second one display it for devices "sm" up (you could use md, lg, etc. instead of sm if you want to show on different devices.

I suggest to read about that before migration:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 12):

```
<div class="small hidden-xs">
    Some Content Here
</div>
```

This also works for elements not necessarily used in a grid /small column. When it is rendered on larger screens the font-size will be smaller than your default text font-size.

This answer satisfies the question in the OP title (which is how I found this Q/A).

Comment: This worked fine. I used this to hide an image. 

<div class="small hidden-xs">
<a href=''link"></a>
</div>